# Is it possible to get reflection metadata when use the decorator function on method dynamically?

Tags: typescript, reflection, nestjs

I'm learning `nestjs`, and now have a method decorator like below:

```js
# my.decorator.ts
export function MyDecorator(): MethodDecorator {
  return (
    target: object,
    key: string | symbol,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) => {
    // output reflection metadata
    console.log(target, key);
    console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', target, key));
    console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target, key));

    SetMetadata(MY_DECORATOR_METADATA, true)(target, key, descriptor);
  };
}
```

```js
# app.service.ts
export class AppService {
  // use decorator directly on **test1**
  @MyDecorator()
  async test1(p1?: string) {
    // use decorator dynamically on **test2**
    MyDecorator()(AppService.prototype, 'test2', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(AppService.prototype, 'test2'));

    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('test1'), 0))
  }

  async test2(p2?: string) {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve('test2'), 0))
  }
}
```

test1 method works well with 'design:*' metadata, but test2 method outputs undefined.

how can i get test2's metadata?
any help?

Comment: compile that into js and check if there's some TS-specific wrappers

Comment: yeah, test2 doesn't have the 'MyDecorator' wrapper

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this would be possible with a dynamic decorator. Typescript needs to know what the decorator is called on during compile time so it knows to emit that metadata. That's where the `design:*` metadata comes from. So if you're running a decorator at runtime, you can dynamically modify *custom* metadata, but the compiler metadata won't exist. You could get around this by ensuring that you add a decorator to the method so that at compile time tsc properly emits, but that's about all you can do

Comment: thanks for your reply! is there any way to get function's parameters without `design:paramtypes`?